# In Titanium JS, how can I change the inactive Tab tint colour?

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I've successfully changed the Tabs background colour and the active tab tint colour. However, I can't seem to change the tint colour of an inactive tab from grey.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the "About" tab text and icon are grey.

Note that the icons are .png image files, which are both white. It looks like they are being overridden with that grey colour.

How can I make them white or another colour?

I've tried the following in my `.tss` file, but nothing has worked:

```
"TabGroup" : { 
   barColor: '#f8ac12',
   tabsBackgroundColor: '#f8ac12',
   tintColor: '#FFFFFF',
   tabsTintColor: '#FFFFFF',
   activeTabIconTint: '#FFFFFF',
},
"Tab": {
    iconIsmask: "false",
    tintColor: '#FFFFFF',  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change an inactive tab's tint color so you should try this [custom tab group widget](https://github.com/jasonkneen/com.jasonkneen.tabgroup).

Answer (score 5):

The Titanium docs have a typo.  The property you need to modify for the tab is "iconIsMask", not "iconIsmask".  This should make iOS should keep whatever the icon's color is.

```
"Tab": {
  iconIsMask: false,
  tintColor: '#FFFFFF'
}
```

Unfortunately, the text remains gray.  I'm trying to figure that out now. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8QLT.jpg

Comment: That's great, if you can figure out why the text remains grey, I'll put this as the correct answer.

Comment: @shrewdbeans The grey text color seems to be a bug in Titanium.  https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-4497  Hopefully it gets fixed soon.